GoRouter nested routes duplication
I'm working on a movie app
My goal is to build this navigation system:

A root menu with these branches: home, search
Both home (/) and search (/search) have a movie card to open movie details page
Opening the movie details page should keep the root menu
UPD: Each navigation tab should have it's own Navigator, so I
have to use a StatefulShellRoute

I've tried having a StatefulShellRoute with the corresponding home and search branches, each having it's own movie details route:
GoRouter(
    routes: [
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack( // Root menu route
            branches: [
                StatefulShellBranch( // Home branch
                    routes: [
                        GoRoute( // Home route
                            path: '/',
                            routes: [
                                GoRoute( // MovieRoute
                                    path: 'movies/:id', 
                                    ...,
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
                StatefulShellBranch( // Search branch
                    routes: [
                        GoRoute( // Search route
                            path: '/search',
                            routes: [
                                GoRoute( // Movie route again
                                    path: 'movies/:id', 
                                    ...,
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)

But this solution has 2 drawbacks:

Opening movie details from search causes '/search/movies/:id' path, while I want it to be '/movies/:id' no matter where user gets there from
Routes duplicating, which is gonna become a hell with the project growth (for example, a movie route will have many of it's own subroutes like franchise, so these routes are gonna be duplicated too)
Movie route gonna become infinitely self-recursioned if I'll try to make a movie route opening from another movie route

Trying to declare the movie route outside the branches causes movie details without root menu
Is there a way to solve all of these 3 problems together?

Can you try moving the movie details route to the root level so the user can navigate /movies/:id irrespective of the routes.
  GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        return RootScreen(navigationShell: navigationShell);
      },
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/search',
              builder: (context, state) => SearchScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/movies/:id',
      builder: (context, state) => MovieDetailsScreen(id: state.pathParameters['id']!),
    ),
  ],
);


On back you will not go back to /search which is not correct.

I did as follow on my app to reuse easily routes. Each route is a class which extend GoRoute.
Each class contain a "go" method which will do as same as go_router.go but with extra stuff like queryParameters, pathParameters and relative path.
You can refer to my code bellow, if you have question please ask :).
I can well handle deeplinks and i can reuse easily every routes everywhere in my app.
My Router :
 GoRouter createRouter({
    List<NavigatorObserver>? observers,
  }) =>
      GoRouter(
        initialLocation: HomeRoute.route,
        observers: observers,
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          HomeRoute(),
        ],
      );

My Home :

class HomeRoute extends GoRoute {
  HomeRoute()
      : super(
          path: route,
          builder: _build,
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            SignInRoute(),
            RegisterRoute(),
            ProfileRoute(),
            SearchAppartmentsRoute(), // contain a nested AppartementsRoutes
            AppartementsRoutes(),
            MyBookingsRoutes(), // contain a nested AppartementsRoutes
          ],
        );

  static const String route = '/';

  static void go(BuildContext context) {
    return context.goUri(route);
  }

  static Widget _build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const AppHomePage();
  }
}

Some extensions to make logic works (go_router 'go' didn't have queryParameters and pathParameters...)

extension UriExtension on Uri {
  String get route => toString().replaceFirst('$scheme://$host', '');

  Uri replaceQueryParameters(Map<String, String?> queryParameters) {
    queryParameters = Map<String, String?>.from(queryParameters)
      ..removeWhere((String key, String? value) => value == null);
    return replace(queryParameters: queryParameters);
  }

  Uri replacePathParameters(Map<String, String?> pathParameters) {
    pathParameters = Map<String, String?>.from(pathParameters)
      ..removeWhere((String key, String? value) => value == null);
    return replace(
      pathSegments: pathSegments.map((String segment) {
        if (segment.startsWith(':')) {
          final String parameterName = segment.substring(1);
          if (pathParameters.containsKey(parameterName) == true) {
            return pathParameters[parameterName]!;
          }
          throw ArgumentError('Missing path parameter: $parameterName');
        }
        return segment;
      }),
    );
  }
}

extension GoRouterExtension on BuildContext {
  void goUri(
    String url, {
    String? additionalPath,
    Map<String, String?>? pathParameters,
    Map<String, String?>? queryParameters,
  }) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(
      additionalPath == null
          ? url
          : "$url${url.endsWith('/') ? additionalPath : '/$additionalPath'}",
    );

    if (pathParameters != null) {
      // This can remove first slash
      uri = uri.replacePathParameters(pathParameters);
    }
    if (queryParameters != null) {
      uri = uri.replaceQueryParameters(queryParameters);
    }

    final String route = '$uri';
    debugPrint(route);
    GoRouter.of(this).go(route.startsWith('/') ? route : '/$route');
  }
}

When i need to create share feature which need path, i can do like that :
 String shareAppartementUrl({required String appartementId}) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
      '${HomeRoute.route}${AppartementsRoutes.route}',
    ).replacePathParameters(
      <String, String?>{
        'appartementId': appartementId,
      },
    );
    return '/$uri';
  }


